# QGIS Python Crashing When trying to Use Layer Functions

Tags: qgis, mapping

I'm running QGIS 3.10 and trying to build a simple export script for an already configured map file, but I keep running into an issue. My code is below.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
#from PyQt5.QtCore import *
#from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = "D:/OSGeo4W64/share/proj"
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = "D:/OSGeo4W64/bin/apps/Qt5/plugins"
os.environ['QT_PLUGIN_PATH'] = "D:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/plugins"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("D:/OSGeo4W64/", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
project = QgsProject.instance()
print(project.fileName())
project.read("D:\MapWorkingFolder\RanchMaps.qgs")
print(project.fileName())
base_path = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath())
pdf_path = os.path.join(base_path, "Ranch_Maps_Atlas.pdf")
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout_1 = manager.layoutByName('ranch_maps_new')
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout_1)
#exporter.exportToPdf(layout_1.atlas(),pdf_path,QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
exporter.exportToPdfs(layout_1.atlas(),pdf_path,QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
#iface.actionExit().trigger()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

It all "works" aka doesn't throw any errors that I notice, but the `exporter` command throws a 6 Iterator Error, and if I manually work in Python3 and try to run any function that accesses the layers Python crashes. I've tested this with a more simple map on the same file, and it works.

Example function the crashes this. `project.mapLayers()`

The map only has 3 layers. 2 PostGIS database layers, and 1 XYZ Tile Layer.

I've searched and tried quite a few things, but without success.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: How are you running this code? is it a plugin, a function or run from the python console?